# Относительные ссылки на markdown из ГИТ, при публикации документов в Confluence через markdown from URL

Tags: git, markdown, confluence

В гит выложена документация в формате  mardown. Документы имеют связанные ссылки на документы и рисунки, которые в гите в веб-форме прекрасно отображаются.  Ссылка делается стандартным образом `[название ссылки] (путь до связанного документа в гит)`

Дальше мы начали использовать плагин  *Markdown from URL* для доступа к документам в маркдаун, выложенных в гит , из Confluence  по URL документа в гит. И вот тут ссылки на связанные документы работать перестают. Подскажите, что делать и как выставить свойство  markdown  таким образом чтобы ссылки стали активными?

Comment: я бы посмотрел, какие ссылки по факту в "гите" (а по факту в гилабе, гитхабе или gogs/gitea) и какие сделал Confluence и что именно он ожидает, а потом уже думал, как выбросить Confluence и тем самым решить проблему:)

Comment: ну ссылки в гите оформляются стандартно ``` [название ссылки] (путь к папке в гите)```  далее в конфлюенц используется плагин  markdown from url с указанием  url на соответствующий документ в гит.

Comment: А Вы точно прочитали то, что я спросил? скорее всего нет. Но даже в Вашем комментарии видно, что скорее всего Вы пишете полный путь к файлам..

Comment: Да, я пишу полный путь с учетом протокола и имени сервера. Надо сказать, что это Битбакет. И битбакет и  конфлюенц на разных серверах....Как тогда указать....

Comment: указывайте относительный путь. Представьте себе, что Вы решили переехать на другой сервер/репу - в Вашей схеме все сломается сразу.

Comment: неее. не катит. пробовал. Но вы натолкнули меня на мысль. А что есть свалить все документы в одну директорию. Или указать  url для документа из  download web  морды битбакета.....

Answer (score 0):

Спустя 2 месяца решение неожиданно нашлось. Я не оьратил внимание на то, что Конфлюенц развернут на сервере с линуксом. А значит вместо прямого "слеш" надо использовать "обратный слеш" принаписании путей до документа, когда оформляешь ссылки. Как только, я заменил "слеши" все заработало.